# Use maven random port in java cucumber test

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I'm using this maven plugin to create a random port for a service and Kafka

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>reserve-network-port</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <portNames>
                                    <portName>kafka.port</portName>
                                    <portName>service.port</portName>
                                </portNames>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Then I'm using surfire to run some Integration test

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>cucumber-tests</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <log.dir>${project.build.directory}/logs</log.dir>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                    <include>**/*Steps.java</include>
                                    <excludes>**/*cucumber.RunCucumberIT.java</excludes>
                                </includes>
                                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Then in my Cucumber step I'm trying to get it through

```
var port = System.getProperty("service.port")
```

But I'm getting `null` value

Shall I need to set in the `surefire` plugin to be visible in my cucumber execution?

Comment: because you need to configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` to include the `argLine` configuration!

Comment: Do you mind provide a response with an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>cucumber-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <log.dir>${project.build.directory}/logs</log.dir>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Steps.java</include>
                    <excludes>**/*cucumber.RunCucumberIT.java</excludes>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            <!-- you must add this line -->
                <argLine>-Dservice.port=${service.port}</argLine> 
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**update**
you can try moving the execution of the `build-helper-maven-plugin` before the execution of the `maven-surefire-plugin` in your POM file!

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>reserve-network-port</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <portNames>
                    <portName>kafka.port</portName>
                    <portName>service.port</portName>
                </portNames>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>cucumber-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Surefire configuration -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

good luck !

Comment: this will make the `System.getProperty("service.port")` call in your Cucumber step to retrieve the correct value instead of `null`

Comment: Now I'm able to receive ${service.port} but it's not replacing the value from the previous plugin. Other plugins that I have is able to do it.

Comment: @paul because the Surefire plugin runs in a separate process from the previous plugin! I will update my answer ...

Comment: <systemProperties> in the plugin is not allowed :(

Comment: @paul don't be upset, we are trying our best to fix it together! I have written another way for you, see if this works?

Comment: No worries mate, I got it!!! I need to set in surefire <systemProperties>
          <service.port>${service.port}</service.port>
         </systemProperties>